# why do I get error 193 with LoadLibrary if exe and target dll are 32bit?

Tags: windows, winapi

After making sure that all my VisualStudio 2010 project options are correct (lib file and paths are correct, and dll file is right next to the exe file)

```
hhandleDLL = LoadLibrary("myclass_dll.dll");
error = GetLastError();
```

GetLastError returns 193.
And the handle remains 0x00000 (NULL) as per initialization.

This 193 error code is typically due to a mismatch between 32/64 bit compilation between exe and dll.
Yet all of my code is compiled in 32 bit (I have triple checked)

Does anyone have a hint on what is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Before checking `GetLastError()`, your real code check what `LoadLibrary()` returns to make sure it failed? Don't go checking error codes unless there actually is a failure.

Comment: Does myclass_dll.dll have a dependency on a 64 bit dll?

Comment: @john none! there are only the exe and the dll. And I wrote both of them and compiled them in 32 bit

Comment: You might think that there are no dependencies, but you could be wrong. Debug this with loader snaps enabled and see which dependent DLL load attempt fails.

Comment: Define an explicit path, so you can be sure to load the DLL from the place you "triple checked"..